# When is $(a^b)^c $ = $a^{bc}$ true?

Tags: exponentiation

I know that in some cases this rule is not true. For example

$$((-1)^2)^\frac{1}{2}\ne(-1)^{(2\cdot\frac{1}{2})}$$

So when is this rule true ?

Comment: from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents), it's true while $a>0  \quad and \quad  b,c \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Related: [For which complex $a$, $b$, $c$ does $(a^b)^c=$a^{bc}$ hold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347504/for-which-complex-a-b-c-does-abc-abc-hold/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true when $a>0$ and $b, c \in \mathbb R$. In this situation we have a canonical choice for a value for $a^b$, given by $e^{b \ln a}$, using the principal branch of the natural logarithm on positive real numbers (that is, the one that gives $\ln a \in \mathbb R$).

For other values of $a$ there is no natural choice for $\ln a$, so $a^b$ has multiple equally valid answers. What is true is that each value of $a^{bc}$ is equal to a value for $(a^b)^c$, but not conversely. For instance, in the example you gave, $a=-1, b = 2, c = \frac{1}{2}$, the values of $a^{bc}$ are

$$(-1)^1 = e^{\ln(-1)} = e^{\pi i + 2\pi i n} = -1,$$

and the values of $(a^b)^c$ are

$$( (-1)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1^{\frac{1}{2}} = e^{\frac{1}{2} \ln(1)} = e^{\frac{1}{2} 2\pi i n} = \pm 1.$$

Comment: And if we separately discuss $a=0$ on which $\log a$ is undefined we are done.

Comment: Actually, I've never seen what a good description of $0^z$ should be in general... Obviously $0^a = 0$ for $a \in \mathbb R^{>0}$, and I know $0^0$ is indeterminate, I believe with possible values in the interval $[0,1]$? And it only makes sense to have $0^{a}$ be undefined/infinite for $a \in \mathbb R^{<0}$. Not sure about more general complex values of $z$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: It is a misunderstanding to even use the word "indeterminate" unless you're looking at a limit. The expression $0^0$ unambiguously has the value $1$ -- "indeterminate" applies only if you have a _limit_ of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both go towards $0$. In that case "indeterminate" means neither more nor less than the fact that knowing these limits does not determine what the limit of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, I was referring implicitly to limits; it's just been a long time since I've done Calculus, so I didn't make it explicit when I should have. I don't think it's unfair to say that $0^0$ itself is "multivalued" or "indeterminate". Assigning a value of $1$ to $0^0$ is *useful*, for many reasons in mathematics, but at the same time I think it's misleading to say that the value of $0^0$ is unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

The main two cases where this rule holds are

1. When $a$ is a positive real (and $b, c$ are real).
2. When $b$ and $c$ are both integers.

In the latter case it holds not only for multiplication of numbers, but in any group.

The *prototypical case* of exponentiation, where base and exponent are both positive integers, is a special case of each of these situations.

Answer (score 2):

If $b,c$ are integer numbers than the rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ is true for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. If at least one of the two exponent is a real non integer number than the rule is true only for non negative basis $a$.