# Restriction when use $a^{p/q}=(a^{1/q})^{p}$

Tags: exponentiation

What's the restriction (for $a, p, q$) when I use the following in proof?

$a^{p/q}=(a^{1/q})^{p}$

The calculus book give a list said:

$a$ $real$, $q$ $odd$ --------------- $a^{1/q}$, called the $q$th root of $a$, is the number $b$ such that $b^{q}=a$

$a$ $nonnegative$, $q$ $even$ ---- $a^{1/q}$ is the nonnegative number $b$ such that $b^{q}=a$

$rational$ $exponents$ -------- $a^{p/q}=(a^{1/q})^{p}$

I'm mess up by these restrictions.

Comment: can this help? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495532/when-is-abc-abc-true?rq=1

Comment: @juniven In the book it said that $a^{1/q}$ when $q$ is even and $a$  $nonnegative$, your link said the restriction is $a>0$, which is different

Comment: Why not put that comment in your question?

Comment: @juniven added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of complex numbers, the left side is 
$$\exp\left(\frac{p}{q} \log(a)\right)$$ and the right is
$$\eqalign{\exp\left(p \log(a^{1/q})\right) &= \exp\left(p \log\left(\exp\left(\frac{\log(a)}{q}\right)\right)\right)\cr
&= \exp\left(p \left(2 \pi i n + \frac{\log(a)}{q}\right)\right)
\cr &= \exp(2\pi i np) \exp\left( \frac{p}{q} \log(a)\right)}$$
where $n$ is any integer.  There is always at least one branch ($n=0$) of the right side that makes this true, while if $p$ is an integer it is always true.

Comment: btw, from which topics could I learn that the $2\pi i$ transformation you do in your formula?

Comment: Complex analysis.  See e.g. Chapter 3 of [these notes](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/complex.html)