# What is solution of $j^3$ (j is complex number)?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a confused with this problem? I calculate this by 2 ways:
$$j^3 = jj^2 = j(-1) = -j$$
$$j^3 = j^{\frac{12}{4}} = (j^{12})^{0.25} = 1^{0.25} = 1$$
Why does it have different result?

Comment: $1^{0.25}=1^{\frac14}=1,-1,j,-j$. The roots other than $-j$ are extraneous.

Comment: Same as why $(-2)^3=-8$ and $(-2)^3 = (-2)^{\frac{12}{4}} = ((-2)^{12})^{1\over4} = 4096^{1\over4} = 8$ seem to give different results.

Comment: Related: [For which complex $a$, $b$, $c$ does $(a^{b})^{c} = a^{bc}$ hold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347504).

Answer (score 2):

In  the complex number field $x^{\frac{12}{4}}$ is not a single valued function because we have four fourth roots of a complex number, so we cannot write $j^3=j^{\frac{12}{4}}$.

Comment: Thank for your reply Emilio, Like Aritra calculate (-2)^3 it also have 2 solutions. It make me confused :'(

Comment: $-2^{\frac{12}{4}}$ has the four values: $-8,8,-8j,8j$.

Comment: So if i calculate by pocket calculator, I press (4096)^0.25 it has only equal = 8; not have result -8 (assumed we use R field, not complex field)

Comment: Generally a pocket calculator give only the principal root, that , in the case of a fourth root is the positive real value. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalSquareRoot.html